Bidirectional Solar inverter circuit confusion
I has seen a solar inverter design and have some confusion regarding the inverter circuit I have drawn myself from an inverter. The circuit is shown below. As far as I understood going from left to right along red arrow is the circuit which charges the battery when the solar bus voltage is there. This comes from an MPPT circuit. But I am having the following confusions regarding the opposite direction.

How does the inverter works when the battery is discharging? Are the IGBTs working in some sort of rectifier configuration? can someone explain if that is a rectifier because I cannot make some rectifier sense from it.
What is the use of the inductor and the diode (DSEP60-06A)? I can make a conclusion that it works as a buck converter when acting along red arrow but there wasn't any strong capacitor across the H-bridge to make it perfectly DC for the buck.

Kindly help me explain this circuit configuration as I haven't seen such a circuit before.


You might have carried some errors over from wherever you copied it. Best to show the original and make a decent linked citation. If you are going to refer to an inductor and a diode please use the reference names from the schematic.
